# Maybe, add posibility to just pass "fast bounty" to other post to show your "gratitude"?

Tags: feature-request, bounty

Just yesterday I noticed that quite old and quite famous post - [why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) - was offered a bounty with explanation: "

> One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.

Since this question for sure does not need bounty to get peoples attentions (606111 views) - then maybe just add possibility, with a single click, to give some reputation to other post. I mean - to prevent using bounty for this.

I never think that such feature is needed - but obviously it seems that it would be used.

Comment: This is a multidupe, but they all live on [meta.se]

Comment: Meh, there's more than one motivation here.  Could be gratitude, could also be a conviction that more people should see it.  An antidote for [trivial crap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201718/concatenating-two-stl-vectors) getting more views than this worthy one.

Comment: The worry is that people would start doing shady underground economies. Calling each other up "hey drop 200 on my question, before 2PM"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The bounty is *supposed* to draw attention.  The hope is that this drives extra upvotes to a good answer, as an additional bonus on top of the bounty itself.

If we offered instant bounties for this, people would use them instead of traditional bounties, and the answerer wouldn't get that extra rep boost.  We could only offer this on really famous questions, but that seems like a solution in search of a problem.  Are there a lot of really famous questions getting bounties and clogging up the featured page?  Looking at it now, no.

Comment: I don't need it to draw attention. Literally someone just solved a problem I had for years. I want to reward that solution with extra rep. And I have to wait 24 hours for that? That's just foolishness.

Comment: @corsiKa: Stack Overflow cares more about the answerer's needs than your needs.

Answer (score 4):

SO does not have functions to immediately donate reputation to other users because (among other reasons) these functions would be abused by sock-puppeteers. Right now, if a sock-puppeteer wants to "load" a sock-puppet with reputation, it is not *impossible*, but the puppeteer has to work at it, and it leaves a visible activity trace. Because these activities are visible, it is possible for non-moderators to notice suspicious patterns and report them for further investigation. We do not want to open a avenue by which sock-puppeteers can load their puppets by means of a single and not very visible operation.

There's no denying it would be nice to be able to gift people without having to go through the bounty system but it would cause the problem I've explained above.

Comment: I think this is a very weak argument against the instant bounty for existing answer. It's already quite simple to catch sock puppets, so much so that the process is mostly automated. If it makes it any better, you could let the benefactor award it now and let the beneficiary receive it in 24 hours...