# User does not speak English and duplicates questions

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, new-users, languages

A new user has an issue and asked a question about it days ago. His sentences were weird, and I imagined he did not speak English great and used a translator.

I wrote an answer that I made as clear as I could, but he did not understand and added seven comments within few minutes telling he doesn't get it and asks for more help. I explained to him that he should not do that and I added a simplified explanation in vain and also wrote that I have nothing more to explain and that he should take more time to read.

Two days later the question was deleted and [copy-pasted to a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32493622/meshes-scale-without-altering-the-position-in-three-js).

It appeared he had asked a total of 6 questions for 3 different issues, the last 3 being extended versions or duplicates of the first 3. The first have all been answered correctly, followed with comments of his meaning he does not understand and needs more help, while every needed word are one line above.

None upvoted nor validated until I asked him to. I flagged/commented problematic posts, and for the last one clicked 'alert a moderator' and explained the issue in the input.

Today another user asked [a second carbon copy of the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32578134/how-to-scale-multiple-meshes-to-or-from-the-middle-of-it-three-js). This also led me to [a question I did not see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557407/get-real-coordinate-that-occupies-a-mesh-in-the-scene-three-js) from the first user, a simplified version of his problem that received a correct answer, but with no vote/validation.

This is a total of four same questions, one deleted, one simplified, with two answered correctly. How can he be stopped?

Comment: Basically by downvoting the questions if they are unclear. You can also vote to close as duplicates providing the duplicate is not deleted and either the duplicate target has an answer or the user is the same.

Comment: @RobertLongson unfortunately i cannot flag those questions as duplicate because he did not upvote/validate any answer

Comment: @Atrahasis If the questions are all duplicates of questions he's asked, they don't have to have an answer at all to be flagged as duplicate. (Basically, a question can be closed as a duplicate of a question regardless of having an answer so long as the same account asked them.)

Comment: @Kendra so this is the issue :) Because the first one is related to one account but has been deleted, the second one is the first that we can access then (but unanswered), the third is a simplified version - that has an answer from so else - and does not deserve to be flagged, and the last one is from another account. I will may have to wait the fifth question then.

Comment: My first impulse is to find out what his native language is, then find another native speaker who can explain the answers to him in Chat. My second impulse is to explain to him (in plain English that will survive machine translation) that *he* must find such a translator, and that he is being a nuisance. My third impulse is to accept the fact that he is not intelligent/considerate enough to have done this already, and vote to close every unclear question I see.

Comment: If there's a Stack Overflow in this person's native language, we should direct them there. [Portuguese](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/), [Spanish](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/21519/the-stack-overflow-in-spanish-project-is-underway)

Comment: The language is indeed Spanish. Most of the untranslated words in his snippets are, modulo accents, the same across both Portuguese and Spanish, but `datos_extrusion` gives it away (in Portuguese it would be "dados (da) extrusão" rather than "datos (de la) extrusión"). Going on a tangent, it seems that no one has tried to post a question in Spanish at pt.stackoverflow yet -- several obvious searches don't bring anything, and there are no meta discussions about such a scenario. I find that slightly surprising.

Comment: @Beta the Chat is a good solution, thanks

Comment: I speak spanish and in one comment he wrote "contestarme" which indeed is spanish. I don't have an expertise on JS, know basics of those topics, but if you want, I can translate it for you by now.

Comment: It looks likely that the Spanish-language SO will be open soon. Once it's open, can we direct this user to that website?

Comment: Yeah @Kevin I guess it would be the best option, but I guess we still can help him this way by now, then once it's open, help him to get into SO in Spanish. Maybe we can still give him some feedback before he gets into Spanish SO :)

Comment: @Frakcool thanks ! I sumed up a bit the reactions here to answer him in a comment this morning and I proposed him to speak Spanish on chat too, though I don't speak much this language. He doesn't seem to have read the comment seriously in his reply. He also claims his friend doesn't have enough rep to speak in chat (Is that possible ?) while skype or whatever could work. If you want you can do the same,if the author is not me he may take more care of what is written now. What is sad for him is that the problem is a very little piece of logic, it is easy to understand and probably to translate.

Comment: @Atrahasis I got lost in between all links and duplicated questions. Where in all of them is where I should comment and maybe translate your answer. Leaving a comment there or something in spanish so I can talk with him later, since atm I can't skype with him since I'm at work and after that I go to school, maybe at night (in 10 hours from now) we could meet (OP, you and me) on a chat session through Skype or something where I'd be merely a translator for both sides. I don't know if it fits you and OP too.

Comment: @Frakcool yes why not, it is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32578134/how-to-scale-multiple-meshes-to-or-from-the-middle-of-it-three-js). I'm in Europe and in 10 hours it will be 5:30 am for me, and i don't even know where the OP leaves. Also the full explanation was deleted with the first question so it is not reachable now. But I could explain you the issue before, as i wrote it just is a problem about logic. I will keep reading comments on his question and if he's ok i will link my skype.

Comment: As for the map he posted I supose he's from Spain, I'm from Mexico in 10 hours it will be 10:30 pm here, let me check it :)

Comment: @Atrahasis I added 2 comments (1 in spanish and 1 in english, both with same information) on the link provided. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @Frakcool actually I won't do my best to be right on time, spend 1h more for him and be sure he understands, all that for free and 0 reputation (since i definitely won't work to sum up the discussion and write a nice SO answer that could make me gain a few tens of rep ^^). Given the state of mind he has i think it won't be easy to have a good discussion, independantly of language. Here is the deal i propose : he deletes the active question. He undeletes his original question (bottom of question tab in profile) then you see what he doesn't understand in the long answer + comments i yet wrote.

Comment: @Frakcool that is actually what i told him in my last comment. We can't do  all those huge efforts for a very simple thing while he shows very little efforts about it too, it is his problem first. If he doesn't even understand he has to close this question and undelete the original, while we are proposing him a 1h-chat session, with a free professionnal and a free translator, heh what the heck ! he is not a child, we can't care about him that much.

Comment: I'm with you about being on time and etc, and about it's his problem. Also if he doesn't reply today well, too bad. We're gonna try to help him, with the conditions you say, but I need him to reply too so I can tell him to do so. Anyway let's just wait for his reply :)

Comment: @Atrahasis I already told him about undelete his original post, he's from Colombia and as I looked in Google he's just 1 hour after me, maybe tomorrow would be a nice day for us to meet. He said he could work at night if needed (but I don't), so let me have a talk with him once he undeletes original post, maybe I'll mention you there through comments in case I don't understand it at all. Although he can join chat rooms which is great in case we can't chat all together, but you write, I translate whenever I have time available, he replies, and so on...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Well this can't be a general answer, but this is how the story ends, with all the help this question has received.

I had quickly concluded the same as in the most voted comment from Beta, i.e. the user has been showing no understanding he is a nuisance and that we cannot beg to help him longer in return.

However Beta added the idea of using the chat. I had happily reached the 'create chat rooms' privilege recently and this seemed an idea to try, because without the language barrier the user may feel more comfortable. Although I had nothing to gain by solving his issue (25 rep maybe, compared to the time I had yet spent with him), I just wanted to point him to the correct path, as he was still posting other questions that were duplicating existing ones, without validating answers and commenting that he does not understand. I wanted to know how to get him understand this is not correct behaviour, as some can't sleep when they don't solve a mathematical issue or whatever.

So I proposed to him the chat idea in a comment, but it also required Frakcool to translate the problem and basic good practice in his language, plus required that he repeat the proposal, to get the user to understand (after 4 days) what he had to do. Frakcool finally got him to undelete [his first post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446758/scale-a-mesh-without-changing-the-position-in-three-js)! Congratulations to him.

After that we finally had a 2h SO-chat session (from 1am to 3am for me) where we calmly solved the issue, in Spanish. The user added he was anxious because, though he is conscious his English is not great, the problem was about a study project that his diploma depended on.

So I just had a deep relaxing sleep, thinking Frakcool and I had solved an annoying problem and been useful for someone's future.

Still the duplicates have to be deleted, and his same behaviour on other posts be corrected, let us hope to see that be done soon :)

Can we have a T-shirt for this?

Comment: I added a bounty on OP's original question to you, I'll be able to award it tomorrow. Why? Because of your great effort on helping this new user who had no idea on how SO works, hopefully Spanish SO will solve some of these issues. I feel bad for not showing up yesterday for chat session, but I'm glad you could help him with patience in Spanish. I'll add a comment to chat session on your answer on OP's original question so in case it's needed in the future, people will have that help (even when it's in spanish) and I'll try to translate it :)

Comment: Huge tip o' the hat to both of you. Now I have a question/answer to point to when the next complaint rolls in about Stack Overflow users being unhelpful, unfriendly, and/or elitist.

Comment: (Thinking) If you feel one of your accepted answers is "exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty", just point me towards it. In the vein of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297338/2564301 (but sans the Irony Quotes in the title, which seem out of place actually).

Comment: @Jongware Thanks ! I will surely not answer no. The question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446758/scale-a-mesh-without-changing-the-position-in-three-js/32454356?noredirect=1#comment53154070_32454356), as you wish :) I was so tired yesterday because of helping him half the night, i let my keys in the ignition in the middle of town. I was sure I had forgot something but could not know what. I realized it 3h later.