# Dealing with answers to which neither 'very low quality' nor 'not an anwer' apply

Tags: discussion, answers, flags

Recently I've flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34898459/1841194) as "very low quality", but I've just noticed that my flag was declined :

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

I didn't flag it because of being wrong or inaccurate. I flagged it because it has a very low quality as an answer. I think it would be better if it were to be posted as a comment not an answer.

Also I can't flag it as "not an answer", because it as such attempts to answer the question and solve the problem, however it doesn't seem good as an answer.

In such cases what should I do?

---

**Update #1:**

All the guys here say I should downvote, but if you hover the cursor over the downvote triangle it says:

> This answer is not useful.

What I'm saying is that it *is* useful, but it doesn't deserve to be as an answer. An answer should be with more details.

Comment: downvote of course. You could also edit it so that it looks more like an answer than a thank you.

Comment: @KevinB What about fields I'm not familiar with? Also downvotes cost me `-1` :)

Comment: Cmon now, -1 doesn't hurt your reputation at all. Don't be stingy with downvotes. (or with upvotes for that matter). If a post deserves a downvote, give it one

Comment: I've made some edits. The post still isn't very helpful, so downvotes are valid, in my opinion. The answer only adds an additional step of restarting their computer "I wanted to delete an installation and reinstall the content, so I deleted the install files and restarted my computer"

Comment: I don't think it being self answered makes it any more or less helpful to the community.

Comment: "What about fields I'm not familiar with?" You skip it.

Comment: @CubeJockey The question is talking about "uninstall", but you edited it as "reinstall".

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto I used the word "reinstall" because OP made clear their intention to uninstall content and then attempt to install again. In the end this is really just turd-polishing. Is this post even on topic? Or does it fall under "tools used directly for programming"? Not positive.

Comment: *What I'm saying is that it is useful, but it doesn't deserve to be as an answer.* - If it's still a bad/low quality answer, then down vote.

Comment: Remember that questions can be deleted by the roomba if closed and down voted. Any rep you lost on the answers will be returned once the roomba did its job. Upvoted answers, however, will keep a question alive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know how many times I will say this, but here it goes:

## PROBLEM QUESTIONS ASKS FOR PROBLEM ANSWERS

If the answer is bad, there is a 11 out of 10 chance that the question is equally bad or worse. Deal with the question instead; don't try to "fix" the answer. In this specific case, you can close the question as "general computing" or "not reproducible".

This is in line with Shog's [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/213575):

> Don't get me wrong, it's still a bad answer - but when the question is kinda asking for bad answers this is to be expected. **Close or flag the question and move on** - this is much more efficient than hanging around to babysit it by deleting every crap answer that inevitably shows up.

Comment: Maybe not quite "11/10" chance, but this is quite often the case.

Comment: @ryanyuyu the statement is under the premise that lim(questions asked -> ∞).

Answer (score 2):

It is an answer; quite simply, it solves the problem at hand.

It also is not ['very low quality'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122447/16587).

So what can you do?

Downvote it, or leave a comment and move on.

The wrong thing to do would be to flag because you lose reputation if you downvote:

> @KevinB What about fields I'm not familiar with? Also downvotes cost me -1 :) – Hi I'm Frogatto [16 mins ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315135/dealing-with-answers-to-which-neither-very-low-quality-nor-not-an-anwer-appl#comment296781_315135)

In fact, using flags as a 'super downvote' is a quick way to have your flags declined. We've seen enough flagging to see it for what it is, and act accordingly.

Comment: I don't agree with this. If there are enough reasons that make a user think that they *need to flag an answer*, they should focus in the question that [inspired that answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315041/792066) instead.

Comment: _"It is an answer; quite simply, it solves the problem at hand."_  If you see the original version, it's more like a "thanks" comment.

Comment: So why didn't you flag it as "not an answer"? that would have been accepted. Or why didn't you leave a comment explaining the issue you had with the answer?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker _"I can't flag it as "not an answer", because it as such attempts to answer the question and solve the problem, however it doesn't seem good as an answer."_

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto One of the reasons to flag it as "not an answer" (from the dialog itself) is "this should be a comment". : "This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether."

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I think this answer has the same quality of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17629454/1841194). And I previously flagged it as "not an answer" and then was declined.

Comment: It has the same 'quality', but the one you flagged as not an answer is actually an answer. it attempts to solve the problem at hand. Q: "How to adjust height of a HTML element to cover all free spaces of it's parent?" A: "just try height:100% in style tag" . How is that not an attempt to answer the question?  Flagging for "not an answer" has nothing to do with the quality of the answer, it has to do with whether or not something attempts to answer the question.  Flagging for 'very low quality' has nothing to do with whether or not it's an answer, it's flagging purely for unsalvageable posts.

Comment: Okay dear George, thanks for your time and consideration.