# Please explain why this qualifies as an answer?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

[I could not find any getMoney method in your class definition that takes a parameter. Are you sure you did not want to use machine.setMoney(input) instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35616065/1)<sup>1</sup> to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35615996/in-my-main-method-theres-a-error-in-out-printlnmachine-getmoneyinput)?<sup>2</sup>

I mean that is a comment. It is a **statement** then **a question requesting more information**.

#### How is this a valid attempt to answer and why should it not be a comment?

<sup>**1**</sup><sub>I linked to the original because that is what I want feedback on. I think Drew had good intentions trying to help make it more of an answer with his edit, but personally I still think it is a comment even with his edit.</sub>

<sup>**2**</sup><sub>Ignore the fact that the question is extremely poor and unclear, that is not relevant or the point, I just added this link because I know someone was going to ask for it.</sub>

Comment: Looking at the [2nd revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35616065/2) it does seem to be an answer.  Maybe it's an answer of the typo variety or just incorrect, but it's an answer nonetheless.

Comment: Hardly worth worrying about. The question is the real problem, it can only attract answers like this. Take care of the question and the bad answer problem solves itself.

Comment: @ryanyuyu - you did not explain why **a statement** followed by **a question asking for more information** qualifies as an answer and should not have been a comment asking for more information, you just state that it is one.

Comment: @CodyGray - it matters in the round because I am trying to get a clear explination of what qualifies as a an answer and **WHY** so I can link to when people ask if things that are reasonably considered NAA are **not NAA** easily.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson based on the small transformation from question to potential solution, the ideas present in question form lead directly to an answer.  Therefore, it's a (terribly unclear and mis-formatted) answer.  In a nutshell, it contained enough answer-y content and just needed a facelift to make it more obvious.

Comment: Did you flag this as NAA and the flag was declined? Or are you asking in general? [I don't see any flags raised from that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35616065/timeline).

Comment: Hmm, I suppose the [epic apple taxonomy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) is not sufficiently clear. It wouldn't be the first time. I don't think you're going to get a programmer's definition of what is and is not an answer. If we could define it that precisely, we'd just teach a machine to reject them.

Comment: @ryanyuyu - so it is almost an answer?

Comment: @ryanyuyu - **I posted a link to the original version for a reason**, that is what I am looking for guidance on, not the attempt to fix it, the attempt to fix it kind of proves my point.

Comment: I have to say, that answer is a heckofalot more correct than the reason selected to close the question.  Tsk, tsk.  Hopefully that is not why you want to get rid of it.  Next time just close it as a typo.

Comment: Regardless of what I picked the reason that is shown is the one that the **majority** of the close voters picked. Honestly I can't remember what reason I picked.

Comment: related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315135/792066

Comment: @Braiam - this area is ambiguous. I get it that the mods do not want to deal with comments and stuff like this. If that is the case then they need to change the wording of the NAA flag and provide a new flag that puts these answers directly in a review cue to let the community deal with them.

Comment: @Tunaki - [yes](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1033275/053d64be86da6844e29a98808aec0d30) but I am not sure what the intented communication of the canned response is supposed to imply other than *do not bother me*.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson and I posted a link to the revision to prove that it had the content of an answer obscured by its phrasing.  That proves my point that it was an obscured answer the whole time.

Comment: Sorry I stole your example by casting that final delete vote. [Here's another one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35656553/366904) if you need it.

Comment: somewhat related: [Should we avoid rhetorical questions in answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300987/should-we-avoid-rhetorical-questions-in-answers)

Comment: @CodyGray - unfortunately that is more of an answer than what I posted. It is cryptic and grammatically painful, but it at least points out correctly how to correct the problem.

Comment: It was an attempt at an answer. I am plowing through the New Answers to Old Questions screen on 10k Tools often not looking at the Question itself but rather for flagging for NAA or a cleanup with an edit. There are other motivations. Such as dispelling the myth that no post is good enough. Why, because a lot of the attempts at post clean up ironically occur by the people in SOCVR where I sit.

Comment: As for NAA, well, some of us are at above 99% success rate. And I would most likely fail with that flag. By the way, TinyGiant and gunner I believe it was wrote a great userscript (Tampermonkey / Greasemonkey) for what is now referred to as that NATO screen. Ask them about it in [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570)

Comment: Cody Gray's example is equivalent to the second revision of the answer you linked. To see this, perform the reverse transformation on his example: "Are you sure the . is not extra in contact_no?"

Comment: Can't see it... <10k

Comment: Awkward as it is, @MsYvette, the full text of the (original) answer (including the lack of formatting) is the text of the first link in this Meta post: "I could not find any getMoney method in your class definition that takes a parameter. Are you sure you did not want to use machine.setMoney(input) instead?"

Answer (score 13):

Does it attempt to answer the question in any way, even if it has a question mark after it?

<sub>(hint: the above text *is an answer*)</sub>

---

Many people confuse "This is not an answer" with "This answer is wrong, incomplete, or doesn't answer the question that was asked."  To alleviate the confusion, rather than focusing on "not an answer," I suggest focusing on **what an answer is not:**

- A commercial advertisement or promotion
- A new Stack Overflow question
- Attempted communication with another user
- Clarifications to the question
- [Gibberish](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMNry4PE93Y)

When you are evaluating an answer for the "Not an Answer" flag, it is helpful to *evaluate the answer in isolation.*  If it's an answer, it will still be an answer without the question.  This technique works because this is how moderators see these answers in the queue.

Finally, if there is any doubt whatsoever about using a Not an Answer flag, cast a custom flag instead, and answer the following question:

- Why is this answer harmful enough to the site that it warrants forcible removal by a moderator?

---

Regarding "convert to comment," I generally only do that when I see content that clearly shouldn't be in an answer (like a bare link to a blog post), but which would cause information loss if I just deleted it.  If you want an answer converted to a comment, cast a custom flag and put "Convert to comment" in the description.

Comment: Thanks for this guidance, I agree with this it is actionable. What I linked to is a **statement** and a **question asking for more information**. Follow your guidance and remove the statement and you are left with a **question asking for more information**. Remove the **question** and you are left with a **statement** that is not an answer. That qualifies it as a **comment** to me.

Comment: When would you convert an answer to a comment? Also, what _is_ a comment?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: I'll grant you that the example you provided could go either way.  Sometimes I will look at the question to see if the answer has any bearing at all on the specific question; your example does.  If I had seen that particular post in the queue, I probably would have marked the flag helpful, but left the answer there.

Comment: @Tunaki - I see what you did there! :-)

Comment: @Tunaki - When an answer is only asking for clarification or additional information, when it is intended as a follow-on to another answer, or when it is only commenting on a side issue or another comment. Short answers that provide potential solutions are still answers. Rhetorical questions are usually still answers. A check I use: if a question is present in the answer, does it need a response from the original asker? In the above-linked answer, no reply to the question posed in the answer is necessary or anticipated.

Answer (score 6):

The question is a little unclear, but the title shows what the asker's problem is: "In my main method, there's a error in out.println(machine.getMoney(input));"

There is indeed no `getMoney` method in their code that takes a parameter, so it is natural that their compiler complains about this.
(Granted that there are a few more points that I expect their compiler to complain about...)

The answer could do with a little more explanation. The second part of the answer, suggesting they use `setMoney`, seems to be wrong in this answer (as they discuss in comments). But a partially wrong answer is still an answer.

Best thing would be if the answerer edited it, and provided a little more detail. But as far as I can see, it is an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Exactly my reasoning for declining, it looks like an attempted answer albeit wrong and not particularly great writing style. A voting problem, not a moderator problem (which incidentally hadn't gotten what I considered to be appropriate votes).