# I have been given a flag ban but I don't agree with it

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, flag-history, flag-ban

It appears that I've been flag banned:

[image]

I guess it's because I've had [3 flags declined in 7 days](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/542251?showDeclined=true)? But I'd say these declines are either incorrect or at worst marginal:

[First question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40172131)
[image]
TBH, I probably selected the wrong flag here, I should of flagged it as spam, but I selected moderator attention. Still, this question WAS deleted.

---

[Second question::](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149037/how-to-write-a-c-sharp-program-for-roman-numerals-arithmetic-operations/40149184#40149184)
[image]
This was flagged as not an answer...I still don't believe this is an answer to the question, It isn't and at least one person  agreed with me:
[image]

---

[Third Question:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/377928/542251)
[image]
This should surely by a comment? I mean it's a bad answer to a bad question.

I do tend to raise quite a lot of flags. Is this wrong? Mostly I raise "not an answer" flags for answers that, well I don't believe are an answer. I'll often add a comment as well and sometimes the answerer will improve their answer, that then results in a declined flag. I wouldn't say I have a bad hit rate here:

[image]

So **85%** of my flags are helpful!

### My Question(s)

Can someone explain why I have a flag ban here? Is this automated or triggered by a mod? If I've been doing something wrong what? If this is automated is it too draconian?

I feel like a get a lot of flags declined incorrectly. If we have an issue with robo reviewers here, then again the automated ban (if it was automated) feels draconian.

Comment: You are aware of the [Your answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) post?

Comment: I upvoted that post, so yes @rene

Comment: You're not using the NAA flag correctly. Bad or wrong answers should be downvoted, not flagged.

Comment: so why is there a delete reason stating *This does not provide an answer to the question*

Comment: [Stay off the NAA unless the answer is just gobbledly gook. The *"attempt to answer*" criteria is so loosely interpreted as anything thing short of a cat walking across the keyboard can be argued to be an *"attempt to answer"* no matter how poor or incorrect and even then someone will try and argue the intent of the cat was to answer the question. NAA is a waste of time unless it is just random characters, it will just get declined and get banned.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317773/please-explain-why-this-qualifies-as-an-answer)

Comment: Don't bother flagging answers on a question that should be downvoted, closed and deleted--unless they are in coordination with the asker for some purpose (e.g., spamming a service).  Just downvote those answers and move on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first one is SPAM and you should have used the SPAM flag. That would prevented the mods from having any workload as most spam ends up deleted with 6 spam flags. Hop in the SOCVR chatroom if you need either confirmation of spam or more spam flags.

The second one is an answer to a question:

> You want us to write the program for you or just give you an idea? 
>   To do that you just need to write a simple parser for each number. First thing that comes in my mind is that you just go through all number and check:
>
> 1. if following character represent bigger number, then deduct sum you have from this number
> 2. if following character represent smaller number, then add this number to sum you currently have.
>
> But it's more difficult to create common number from Roman. Probably there are some rules, I don't know

It doesn't matter if it does not answer **THE** question. Not an answer flags are not appropriate here. Use down votes and comments and once it is at -1 ask for delete votes.

The last one:

> For starters, don't nest script tags. Script tags with a source should be closed immediately and should be under the or and not in another .

I can see why you want to get rid of this but it is a partial answer as the code in the question is indeed nesting `<script>` tags. Deleting it would be an act of destroying a bit of value, which is where the mods are keen on preventing. Again your better option is down voting, leaving a comment to nudge the OP to expand on their answer.

**tl;dr** you have raised three flags that were declined rightfully from my point of view. I do realize it is hard to make the correct judgement calls for NAA and VLQ flags. The SOCVR chatroom did establish a decent track record in making the right judgement calls but even the regulars there get it wrong now and then, leading to heated debates. Feel free to ask the room for advice once your ban has been lifted.

Comment: Just one point, my work firewall blocks the chat rooms, so using chat isn't unfortunatly an option for me.

Comment: The third answer I believe should of been a comment

Comment: @Liam ah, that is too bad, I guess it is asked too much to find a better workplace to prevent your flags being declined ;)

Comment: Not at the moment :) Our firewall, etc is very draconian. Thanks for the response, I suppose I'll wait the ban out...

Comment: @liam the third answer would be better suited as a comment for sure, but it is an attempt to answer and that makes it not a target for the NAA flag but rather to downvote. A good example of when you would flag NAA for something that should be a comment is a request for clarification ("can you add the error log", etc.). If there is zero trace of an attempt to answer, then flag away.

Comment: Ok, so doesn't the second fit into that? *You want us to write the program for you or just give you an idea?* this seems to ask for clarification. I suppose what I'm trying to say here, is sometimes this is a difficult decision to make. I am genuinely trying to improve the site and I'm now somewhat frustrated to have a ban imposed, getting 3 incorrect flags out of 10 in a week can be very easy to trigger sometimes. Now, that said I have gotten to 700 flags without this happening before..... o_O

Comment: It is a mod conspiracy, I tell you...

Comment: *shakes fist impotently at sky*

Comment: @liam no the second doesn't fit into that because there is more to it than only the sentence you zoom in on. It would most definitely be NAA if it consisted of only that one sentence. It is a poor attempt to answer and it needs to be killed with fire, but we can't use the NAA flag to get what we want. It has to follow the process of being downvoted and those downvotes opening up the path to you using your precious delete votes.

Answer (score 3):

The details for flag bans have been described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/295232): at least 10 flags in the past 7 days, of which at least 25% have been declined. Sadly, this doesn't take into account your overall record.

Not-an-answer flags are always tricky; ♦ moderators see a lot of them and if it isn't immediately obvious that it's not an answer, they can decline the flag. As for the third flag, it's on an eight year old answer. The rules weren't as strict as then, that's probably why it wasn't posted as a comment. To clean up all these semi-answers from the past is an impossible task, but personally I wouldn't have declined that flag. I can imagine that new content has more priority, but only the ♦ moderator who declined the flag can tell you why.

Comment: So we should just leave rubbish answers lying around because they're old? How does that *make the internet better*?

Comment: @Liam you can always downvote.