# Why is this spam flag "disputed"?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam, disputed-flags

**TL:DR**, I flagged [this answer as spam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387/lucene-score-results/40436074#40436074), and now I see, the answer is deleted but the flag is "disputed". FWIW, the user account seems to be gone , too.

I checked the [timeline also](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/387/timeline), did not get much idea, what did I miss? Rather, what is the point I should keep it mind before flagging the next possible "spam"?

---

EDIT: I wanted to emphasise on the "disputed" part.

- If the flag category is wrong (which it is, I know now), it should have been rejected.
- If this is useful, it should be marked "helpful".

Why "disputed", specifically? It this just an "isolated case" or anything fundamental I'm missing?

Comment: Read the last line [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317616/4099593).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not spam, as it does not advertise any product or service. The correct flag for this kind of gibberish is ['rude/abusive'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/295232). It *did* draw the attention of ♦ moderators, so that might be a reason why they marked it as disputed instead of declined.

Another reason could be that the post has been deleted and undeleted multiple times. You're linking to the wrong timeline – the answer has its [own timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40436074/timeline). I encountered a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40421553/revisions) earlier this week, when I (rightfully) flagged an answer as spam, and it ended up being disputed as well.

Comment: Same comment as above, _"With all due respect, that should be a reason for "rejection", not "disputed", right? "_ Sorry if this sounds stupid, but am I missing something very obvious here?

Comment: _On the edit part:_, I have a rather large list of wrong flags getting declined and the question/ answer getting deleted anyway. Ye saying they all should have been "disputed", since they also kind of drew attention?

Comment: @SouravGhosh no, maybe you were lucky this time.

Comment: Don't really intended to be _lucky_, rather prefer to be correct. thanks for the MSE post link, sir, clears things now.

Comment: @SouravGhosh good attitude. I think I found another reason why your flag has been disputed, which could be a bug in the system as well.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I was the mod that chose to dispute it instead of outright decline it. There's a bit of confusion still over what flags are acceptable on such posts - given your flagging history, I decided that I'd dispute it so the flag wasn't marked helpful and potentially feed the post into the audit system, but didn't want to outright decline for this case - think of disputed in this case being a softer version of "no - that's not the right flag"... In future, as Glorfindel says - rude/abusive is more appropriate.

Comment: @JonClements well then, that answers it. Thanks. I'll accept this answer then, as this contains the link to the correct approach here, unless you yourself want to post a separate one, let me know.

Comment: @SouravGhosh go ahead and accept this one :)

Comment: @JonClements thanks for the clarification. In a recent situation [things were handled differently](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336947/i-have-‌​been-given-a-flag-ba‌​n-but-i-dont-agree-w‌​ith-it/336948#336948‌​) but I trust you to make the right decisions on this topic.

Comment: @JonClements Can't you add a message along with a disputed flag? Something like (Disputed - Use rude/abusive to flag this)?

Comment: @BhargavRao I'm not a ♦ moderator, but I have *never* seen a disputed flag with a message, so I suppose that's not possible system-wise.

Comment: It's not possible @BhargavRao - the only flags that can be disputed are spam/rude or abusive and that's by clearing the flags. Only accepting/rejecting allows a custom reason to be used.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that @Jon. That's kinda bad. Perhaps if there are more cases like this, we can add a FR on MSE.

Answer (score 1):

That's not spam.  A spam is an inappropriate advertisement of a product, not someone posting nonsense.  That post merits deletion, but not as spam.

Comment: With all due respect, that should be a reason for "rejection", not "disputed", right?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes, it should have been rejected.