# Review an answer that isn't an answer to a question that isn't a question

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, late-answers

**I just failed a Late Answer Review Audit**:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/16273630

As far as I can remember this is the first time I didn't pass in a total of about 400 completed review tasks. **Without clarification from someone with more review experience I would make the same decision again.**

The user that has posted the question is an SO member for 21 days now and has a total of 1 reputation. The user asks us to tell him if he is moving into the right direction with his js-snippet. In my opinion this is not a question (does not meet the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) requirements) and the answer will be primarily opinion based.

The user who answered the question (the answer I reviewed) is an SO member since today with 1 reputation. He pointed out some formatting preferences of his but didn't provide a solution to solve the problem. How could he? There was no real problem!

**These are the two things I need to know:**

1. What *action* should I have taken?
2. What would an answer to a question like that look like in order to not require an *action* from a reviewer.

---

<strike>This question has now been marked as a duplicate to:</strike>
This is a simmilar question: [Change the name and explanation on NAA flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336961/change-the-name-and-explanation-on-naa-flag)

However, I don't see my question to be a duplicate of it because **my confusion originated from the bad shape of the question.** I never had a problem flagging not-answers correctly. But in this specific case I felt the answer was justified because of the question's bad shape and I didn't knew what a real answer to that question would look like. Agreed, having a different flag description might have helped.

The solution to my question is about *seeing the answer in isolation* rather than *writing a better flag description*.

Comment: So all boils down to *"but didn't provide a solution to solve the problem"* and yet you select "no action needed". You reviewed ___the answer___ and if it doesn't provide a solution then use the appropriate actions for non-answers. If you feel that the question is bad as well, that flag that, too.

Comment: Re #2 - The hypothetical answer wouldn't exist. I can't think of an answer to the question that was asked that should be an actual answer instead of a comment. A user couldn't even just finish the function for them; there isn't enough information.

Comment: Consider questions that are resource requests. An answer that just links to a off-site library might, generally speaking, answer the question but it wouldn't be a *real* answer by Stack Overflow standards because link-only answers aren't answers here.

Comment: @Tom So I should have flagged the answer and the question in that specific case?

Comment: So you reviewed a answer, That deserves a downvote or a flag as not an answer or a comment about not using answer for comment. An answer for a question that deserve a downvote or a flag or a comment about SO guideline. You could have done many Quit review and attack the question. Stay in the review and slap this answer. But you act like: Question is bad, answer is bad. Nothing to see here. But you ask for an experienced reviewer, an I'm not as I rage quit those kind of question.

Comment: @DragandDrop *"But you act like: Question is bad, answer is bad. Nothing to see here."* You are right. I see.

Comment: *"So I should have flagged the answer and the question in that specific case?"* You already saw that the answer isn't appropriate, so yes, the correct action is to flag it as such. If you also flag the question or not is up to you and not part of the review anymore. But if you want to flag the question as well, then you can do that.

Comment: It's so funny, I don't understand why people downvote meta questions like this - *this* is exactly what meta is for, for people who are interested in learning the best way to use and moderate the site.* *sigh* *

Comment: I don't think user rep/length of membership is actually relevant to this. Users with much more rep who've been here much longer post stuff like that too.

Comment: @Ajean I wondered too. This was my first meta post. I guess there is no penalty when voting down on meta...or is there?

Comment: @NoelWidmer No, there's no rep changes at all (although there's also no penalty for downvoting *questions* even on the main site).  But hey, don't be discouraged, people on meta are weird.  This was a perfectly good question to ask!

Comment: Wait, this was in the _late answers_ review queue? For an answer that was posted 6 minutes after the question was asked? Ehm, well, if 6 minutes constitutes a late answer, the system sure loves FGITW answers, doesn't it.

Comment: @MrLister - It's one of those obvious red flags that something is an audit.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I really don't think this is a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I tend to agree with Tom in the comments. This is a comment, not an answer. Additionally the question is now closed and will be deleted.

> What action should I have taken?

Flag it as **Not An Answer**

> What would an answer to a question like that look like in order to not require an action from a reviewer.

Maybe an actual answer? This isn't even close to an answer. He rambles about formatting and then ends with `actual thing should work fine`. If he had included a code block demonstrating what he's going on about, the rambling would have been at least acceptable because it tried to answer the question (even if it can't save an otherwise bad question).

Comment: Hmm... The question was "am I going in to right direction with my code", and answer was "yes, though you have some formatting issues you could improve on". Isn't that an answer to the question? Bad answer to a bad question, yes, but an answer.

Comment: @eis That's not really an answer, tho. That's a comment posing as an answer because the user doesn't have 50 rep. As I said, if he had included some code demonstrating what he was talking about it would have been acceptable. There's another deleted answer [on that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43889201/struggling-with-writing-javascript-if-else-statement) that does just that. It was also low quality [but it was an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Comment: [Actually anything but utter gibberish is considered an *attempt* at an answer is an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317773/please-explain-why-this-qualifies-as-an-answer) and will get rejected if flagged as such by a moderator, this is been beat to death over the last two years.

Comment: @Machavity: Yes, it is an answer. It should not be a comment. The comments section is for requesting clarification.

Answer (score 2):

At risk of sounding like the broken record:

## PROBLEM QUESTIONS ASKS FOR PROBLEM ANSWERS

Try to look at the question when you see a problematic answers. Moderators tend to want to evaluate the answers while being brain dead and context unaware like reviewers in the suggested edits queue, when it has been repeated several times, that they shouldn't do this. The system for LQRQ reviewers shows the question for that same reason, so I'm unsure what is the logic behind that through process... it eludes me.

Meanwhile, your safe approach is to redirect your efforts to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have two crucial misconceptions here. The first is that a question mistakenly posted in the answer section must check all the right boxes so it wouldn't be closed if posted as a question before anyone can consider it to be Not An Answer. This is quite wrong; if the post is *at all* an attempt at asking a new question, in the sense of bringing up a new problem that the poster needs resolved, then it is Not An Answer. This has nothing to do with whether or not the post would survive in its current state; usually, in fact, the sort of ignorance that leads to posting a question as an answer makes it difficult to ask a good question.

The second is that an "answer" to a poorly framed question gets a free pass because it's adhering to the requirements of the question instead of the rules of the site. Not so, but far otherwise! *Questions* can be closed because their *answers* are turning out poorly (or, much more often, because their answers are likely to turn out poorly). Not the other way around. So if the question is stated in a way that attracts non-answers, it probably deserves closing (or sometimes protection), and those answers certainly deserve deletion.

Answer (score 0):

[This is from Robert Harvey on what is an answer or not an answer. It directly contradicts the accepted *answer*.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317780/177800)

> Many people confuse "This is not an answer" with "This answer is
> wrong, incomplete, or doesn't answer the question that was asked."  To
> alleviate the confusion, rather than focusing on "not an answer," I
> suggest focusing on **what an answer is not:**
>
> - A commercial advertisement or promotion
> - A new Stack Overflow question
> - Attempted communication with another user
> - Clarifications to the question
> - [Gibberish](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMNry4PE93Y)
>
> When you are evaluating an answer for the "Not an Answer" flag, it is
> helpful to *evaluate the answer in isolation.*  If it's an answer, it
> will still be an answer without the question.  This technique works
> because this is how moderators see these answers in the queue.
>
> Finally, if there is any doubt whatsoever about using a Not an Answer
> flag, cast a custom flag instead, and answer the following question:
>
> - Why is this answer harmful enough to the site that it warrants
>   forcible removal by a moderator?
>
> ---
>
> Regarding "convert to comment," I generally only do that when I see
> content that clearly shouldn't be in an answer (like a bare link to a
> blog post), but which would cause information loss if I just deleted
> it.  If you want an answer converted to a comment, cast a custom flag
> and put "Convert to comment" in the description.

## Always remember the following:

[When is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

> Just remember: if the text of the post contains an honest attempt at
> answering the question, *then it **is** an answer* - so don't flag it
> otherwise, and if you do, don't complain if your flag gets declined.

#### Answers & Apples

If you're still confused, forget about answers. Think about apples instead:

[image: A, NAA, A, NAA, VLQ]

Answers are just like that, but less tasty in pies.

Comment: +1 *This technique works because this is how moderators see these answers in the queue.* Didn't know that, thank you for the hint, will consider it next time!

Comment: This line: *it is helpful to evaluate the answer in isolation. If it's an answer, it will still be an answer without the question.* directly contradicts the guidance in Your answer is in another castle, and previous incarnations of this discussion, specifically this quote by Gilles: @BoltClock “The NAA flag is designed to be obvious.” Yes, obvious in context. **You sometimes need to look at the question to figure out if the post should be deleted altogether, or converted to an edit, or converted to a comment.**

Comment: **Looking at the question is sometimes necessary for an NAA flag.** Custom flags are for non-obvious cases, not for a jQuery answer on a C++ question. **This kind of case should be a canned flag that feeds into a delete queue** (combining VLQ and NAA) **and not handled by mods at all**. from [A minor change to the description of the "not an answer" flag: "the question" → "a question"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/156546)

Comment: Just wondering, did the NAA criteria change or something? I'm surprised to see this post have a negative score because the answers on [this (similar) post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag) are still pretty highly upvoted... on a side note does anybody ever go back and update / downvote these posts, or do we just have a bunch of old upvoted posts with wrong advice floating in the breeze?

Comment: @jrh - they can down vote this all they want, I really do not care, I am just repeating the official SO party line. Everything is an answer no matter how bad as long as it qualifies as an *attempt*. Even *"Did you try X?"* will get declined if flagged NAA. So the highly upvoted and accepted *"answer"* will just get you flagged banned and nasty comments from the pissed off moderators, ask me how I know.

Comment: For example: [This is Not an Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44311448/177800)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson do you have a screenshot? I can't see deleted answers. [Unless you're talking about this one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44309938/4975230)

Comment: it is deleted now and not worth the time to share a screenshot