# How can Stack Overflow be more welcoming?

Tags: discussion, new-users

I have been on Stack Overflow for a little over a year now, and while I've had many of my questions resolved by kind and well-meaning people, I for some reason have never totally felt *welcome* here.  The "why" of that is something I can't quite put my finger on (and that's honestly too subjective and ephemeral to address here anyway).  A more productive question, I thought, might be: **how can Stack Overflow be more welcoming?**

I am not sure what the exact broader goals of this site (or Stack Exchange in general) are, so I don't feel like I can begin to answer this question very well, which is why I am posing it.  But this site (and to a lesser extent Stack Exchange in general) has often felt like a very cold place to me, and judging by some other questions I have found in the meta here, I am not the first to feel this way.  This saddens me, because from what I *do* know, that's not at all what this site strives to be!

Frankly I'm a bit terrified to even be posing this question, but I hope it may lead to some productive conversation.

---

*To clarify,* when I say "welcoming," I mean just as Trilarion mentions below -- **"courteous and friendly and open."**  I.e., that a veteran user would assume the best of a new user, make an effort to understand where they're coming from (e.g. recognizing that what is a simple solution to them may be incomprehensible to the asker, despite the asker's best research and efforts, or that English may not be the asker's first language, etc.), and commend them for taking the time to post their question (and taking the risk, apparently, as it seems by some of the helpful links other have provided, such as [Why is Stack Overflow - and Stack Exchange in general - so scary?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202168) from Josh, I am not the only one who seizes in absolute terror every time they go to post a question).

I recognize that Stack Overflow is meant to be somewhat "academic" as Servy and Cody point out, but speaking both as a former student and as someone currently working in academia, that does not preclude friendliness.  Yes, there are professors whose office hours are very formal, to-the-point, and black & white.  Then there are those professors who insist you refer to them by their first name, who you learn more from than you ever have, and who teach you more than the answer to a simple question of "Where can I use a semicolon?" or "How can I normalize a database?" (okay that second one maybe isn't entirely simple, but I hope you get my point).

There may be some users, as Cody said, who come here hoping for a fast, easy answer with little-to-no effort on their part.  I'm not talking about pandering to those sorts of users.  Those expectations need to be quashed (kindly), because I wholeheartedly agree that Dr. Stack Overflow's office hours should not be that kind of place.  No, Dr. Overflow's office hours – excuse me – *Stack's* office hours – should perhaps seem at first blush to have the same relaxed demeanor of a place like Yahoo! Answers (tremendous emphasis on "seem," because ye gods forbid this place ever turn into that), but behind that relaxed, Converse-wearing demeanor is a wealth of knowledge, tremendous respect for you as a learner and fellow *human*, and subsequently, far more impactful and meaningful authority than some stoic mod with 50k+ rep who closes some newbie's first question as "too broad" because they didn't write it perfectly on their first try.

...

*Deep breath.*

...

I hope that helps a bit.  Apologies for any unnecessary wordiness, and happy to clarify further if need be.

Comment: SO is a place where you go to get answers to your questions, not a place where you go to hang out and have fun with people.  That's very much *by design*.  It's a largely formal environment, as opposed to the much more informal sites that make up much of its competition.

Comment: I think you're asking an unanswerable question. How can we know how to make people feel more welcome when we don't know what's making them feel unwelcome to begin with?

Comment: We are obviously sufficiently welcoming to have well over 12 million questions asked. I don't see this as a real problem. If you can't even point to something that you feel is an actual problem, there is no way this can be a constructive discussion. I feel compelled to point out that Stack Overflow is more like a professor's office hours than an after-work happy hour at the bar. You are supposed to feel comfortable and welcome, but not *too* welcome that you start misbehaving and taking others' effort for granted.

Comment: We're generally nice people; come hang out in chat some time and meet us in a less structured setting.  The problem is that people equate strict quality control with being mean.

Comment: Thank you, @πάνταῥεῖ, for the link to that question.  It does address to an extent what I'm trying to ask here.  I don't feel that it is an exact duplicate though, because I'm not trying to figure out the root cause of any negativity, rather, I'm trying to find out what could be done to help new users feel less scared and more empowered.

I must unfortunately step away from my computer right now, though I will check back in later.  Thank you to those who have responded.

Comment: @BilltheLizard We *do* know what makes people feel unwelcome, because they write Meta posts about it every other week. The problem isn't that we don't know, it's that we disagree.

Comment: Related: [The rudeness on Stack Overflow is too damn high](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262791), [Why are Stack Overflow users more passionate about Stack Overflow than helping people?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315018)

Comment: *how can Stack Overflow be more welcoming?* Why would that be needed? I mean, which users are bailing out because of me being unwelcome? If I scare away new but knowledgeable users then that is an issue I need to address. But I still have the feeling that most users  that feel unwelcome simply have different expectations. They expect a forum of even worse, facebook. Those who don't realize that are lost for this site. And to be honest I don't think that is an issue that needs to be solved. Because that leaves more time for those that do understand why this site is different.

Comment: @Rene you mean if I come into your house with muddy shoes and put them on your couch and you tell me to not do that and go away.... it isn't you being rude?! come on....

Comment: But @Patrice, no one told me that was considered rude.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot if you come like Patrice to my house, how did you expect me to react?

Comment: There's nothing more welcoming to SE than getting your question downvoted on Meta.  That isn't a joke.

Comment: For you, be nice @Braiam

Comment: @Will indeed, I remember that my very first question on Meta (about weird Swastika patterns in lots of Gravatars, which are totally a thing) was heavily downvoted. I was very put off at first but somehow it worked out

Comment: I reopened this question, because it is a fair question to ask, and is not created as a rant. I do not think it is hyper focused on negativity, but instead is asking how can we be more welcoming. I think this is an important topic and something the community should be more aware of in general anyway.

Comment: [Why is Stack Overflow -- and Stack Exchange in general -- so scary?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202168)

Comment: @Tyler We already had one cycle over that one.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That doesn't matter.

Comment: For the record, I voted to close as _Too Broad_, not duplicate, because of "I for some reason have never totally felt welcome here. The "why" of that is something I can't quite put my finger on..." and "I am not sure what the exact broader goals of this site [...] are..." This needs to at least be grounded in some definition of "welcoming" and the way that characteristic is currently lacking to be a useful starting point for discussion. Otherwise it's just going to turn into another Rorschach blot interpretation session like "Why is SO so negative?" did.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I think you just spelled a perfect candidate for custom close reason at meta: **Rorschach blot**

Comment: I think it would do well as a replacement for "primarily opinion-based", @gnat.

Comment: Marked as reopen. This question asks primarily for possible measures to be more welcoming, the alleged duplicates don't (primarily). That deserves additional discussion.

Comment: But it doesn't make any suggestion as to what "welcoming" might be, @Trilarion, which makes it textbook "too broad" and not a suitable discussion question. It's like asking if anyone has any ways Stack Overflow could be more green.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree somewhat and would like for the asker to add his definition of welcoming although I don't see it as that bad. There is a usual definition of "welcoming" which means something like being courteous and friendly and open. Sometimes I have the feeling people here want things defined especially if they don't like them. So maybe Violet can add a few sentences in order to make the question ontopic?

Comment: Upon recent reflection, I concluded people may probably find SO to be "unwelcoming" because they show up asking a question, expecting to get a fast easy answer, when instead what sometimes happens is experts ask them follow-up questions, point out misunderstandings and wrong assumptions, and argue why they should never actually be doing the thing they're asking how to do. In other words, a lot of people ask about XY problems, and the community calls them out on it. Now, I think this is *a very good thing*, but if you just want code to copy and paste, you're going to be frustrated by it.

Comment: *How can Stack Overflow be more welcoming?*  ... score: **-19**. Oh the sweet irony!

Comment: A new StackOverflow employee lady had a very similar question recently and she got like 100's of upvotes. You're a well meaning average joe and you get -18. Ain't life unfair?

Comment: Related: *[Does Stack Exchange really want to conflate newbies with women/people of color?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366665)*

Answer (score 16):

I assume this is not about a certain right-out rudeness that is prevalent here and there on Stack Overflow and a real problem, but about a certain absence of a community feeling.

Stack Overflow *is* kind of "cold" by design: it's striving to be an encyclopedia, and a place that has very little social "features" and focuses on the hard facts.

This is very central to SO's concept and (many of us here will argue) its success. Both to keep the quality of the content up, and to make it possible for busy professionals to donate slices of their time here with a minimum of distraction.

There's probably no way to completely change the fact that this focus doesn't do much to create community spirit. You'll occasionally run into people who go out of their way of being nice, and some who are more curt (which does *not* necessarily mean they're rude, or even unwelcoming. Tech people can be like that sometimes.) Sometimes you'll run into jerks.

SO is probably not a great place to find mentoring, a nurturing community of like-minded people, or to network, apart from the occasional contact that arises from two people running across each other on the site. (so far, I've met about twenty people in real life who I met here!)

Back when SO was a smaller site where people knew each other, the entire place used to be much more informal and relaxed. That soon moved to Meta, where folks would hang out and a lot of fun content would be posted alongside serious discussions about the site. But as the sites grew, Meta got more formal and rule-oriented, too - the unavoidable result of the place's widening scope, like a small business that grows into a medium-sized or big one. The days of [Meta fun](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta) are almost over.

I'd say the most community feel you can get in the various chat rooms, where people know and interact with each other. There's regular flavoured chat rooms on [chat.stackoverflow.com](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) and the more <strike>insane</strike> quirky places on [chat.meta.stackoverflow.com](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com).

Another place to find a more actively welcoming tone is in some of the broader Stack Exchange communities, which are smaller and some of them more of a family touch.

Comment: But you don't really address *how can Stack Overflow be more welcoming?* you only state facts we all know.

Comment: @rene true. Added a sentence

Comment: that doesn't need a sentence, that needs a sequel ... ;)

Comment: (there is no more chat.meta.so)

Comment: @TravisJ then I've been hanging out on a nonexistent site all those years?

Comment: We didn't want to tell you ... sorry

Comment: @rene a new form of hellbanning?

Comment: @Travis your deleted answer is worth having around (although I might end up arguing against), certainly worth saving for when someone brings that issue up specifically

Comment: But couldn't you "focuses on the hard facts" and at the same time be courteous and friendly? What have content (cold, hard facts) and the way we organize ourselves (we are one team with a common goal and we all like each other...or not?) have to do with each other? Can't even larger amounts of people still get along informal or is this impossible?