# Motivation behind answering Stack Overflow questions

Tags: discussion

I am amazed by how much interaction there is on Stack Overflow and how many helpful people there are on this platform! I was just curious what the motivation is behind wanting to help each other and contribute? Is it to help teach others or the pure kindness of giving back?

This community is great! Thank you!

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3742/344196

Comment: I would take special note of [Why are Stack Overflow users more passionate about Stack Overflow than helping people?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315018/424903) - from your description it seems like you are seeing what you want to see and what you want to see conflicts with the actual goal of the site. Teaching is not one of the goals, it is at best a happy byproduct. We're basically information hoarders, really.

Comment: It is good to also know about the positive stories like this one, and not always [the negative ones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_ZK0t9-llo) (see some of the 1,890 comments). There is also [a response to it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sMIslcynm0Q).