# Is it illegal to create a new similar question to answer a closed one?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This question has been closed: [Travel Salesman Problem - maximize score of visited nodes within a given time frame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74456982/5089567)

Someone else created a new question and answered it instead of waiting for the other one to be reopened: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74464006/5089567

The new question and answer have been flooded with downvotes

Is it illegal to create a new similar question to answer a closed one?

Comment: It is definitely frowned upon to circumvent curation. Nobody is in a hurry here. Just wait for a post to go through review.

Comment: In addition to rene's comment, it is generally not forbidden to repost a question and answer it. This can be suitable when the original question has been deleted for some reason. But make sure the question is on-topic and of good quality. The new question in this case is still off-topic, that's why it got downvotes and has been closed. Also mind that a question must be usable and understandable on its own, it shouldn't rely on a different question (or an off-site resource) to be clear.

Comment: " Just wait for a post to go through review. "  I have done this many, many times.  It doesn't work.  The OP is discouraged and never returns.

Comment: " make sure the question is on-topic "  How? People close requests for algorithms ( my favorite kind ) AFAIK such questions should be OK.

Comment: In this jurisdiction, not illegal, although you might find a district attorney willing to press charges if you shop around... (A bit of fun at the reinstatement of the "illegal" word in the title).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Certainly not, as long as you're not reposting your own question to avoid downvotes/closure/other moderation.

In the example, though, several things are going on:

1. The original close reason was not resolved, as far as I can tell, so applies equally to the new question as it did to the old question when it got closed. At least, there were no major deviations from the original question, nor has the original been edited substantially
2. The original question is still under review, the user appears to post the duplicate without awaiting review
3. The new question does not appear to deviate from the original question at all, so is a duplicate. Duplicating a question while they are under review is a bad move, if the original question is reopened the new question should get closed
4. The new question depends on a closed, downvoted question which will be cleaned up by the roomba if nothing changes. That will make it impossible for users that haven't earned the privilege to view duplicates to understand the question. It should be self-contained, with proper attribution

Any of these points would be enough to be critical of the new question, combining all 4 is, well, not good.

Comment: What is this review you mention?  Closed question are almost never re-opened, thus wasting any work that serious people have done to prepare an answer.

Comment: @ravenspoint At the top in the close banner, you can see _The community is reviewing whether to reopen this question as of 1 hour ago._. If a question is closed incorrectly, and remains closed past the review, you can bring it to meta to discuss if both the users closing the question and those indicating it should stay closed in the review queue were wrong, and then more users can weigh in. If questions that are actually closed incorrectly remain closed and you don't bring it to meta, you're not part of solving that problem. But I rarely see questions edited into shape remain closed

Comment: A question that is edited to be a good question, can end up being reopened.  The closed questions that are not reopened, probably were not edited to be good questions.  OK, there are probably a few misses, but that is the general story.  "Serious people", vis-a-vis the site, should also be serious about encouraging good questions and discouraging poor questions.

Comment: "At the top in the close banner, you can see ...."  Never noticed this

Comment: @ravenspoint I've never noticed it either. The UX design of SO isn't the best sadly

Comment: Now I see it.  Note: it is at the BOTTOM of the banner.

Comment: Apologies, I meant "at the top of the question". You can also generally assume a question is in the reopen review queue if it has recently been edited substantially, or a reopen vote has been cast recently, and it hasn't been in the reopen queue previously (you can check that last fact by visiting the timeline, where completed reviews are visible but not those in progress, which also has some UX problems).

Comment: That sounds complicated.  The flood of downvoters and closers that have infected this site are causing harm that requires something much more straightforward to fix.  My suggestion:  give noobies a chance to fic their questions - disallow closing noobie questions for 24 hours so well intentioned people get a chance to comment and answer.

Comment: @ravenspoint it's not a reliable statistic but in the last 24 hours 750 questions with the tag `javascript` have been added, not allowing to close any of them immediately would be a madness

Comment: 24 hours does not seem too long to wait to see if a question might attract a good answer, or even an improving edit.  Letting questions be closed within moments of being asked prevents well intentioned people from contributing to the ruthless pursuit of perfection.

Comment: @ravenspoint and who will look at those questions? The chance of an unanswered question (in a high-frequency tag) being found hours after it was created is minuscule. 750 questions in a day is **25** Pages of questions. Don't tell me you look at everyone of those.

Comment: I never told you to look at any of them.  I just ask for forbearance while someone else looks at them.  Closing questions prematurely kills the chance they can be improved - even answered.

Comment: Isn't this problem (new users having poorly written questions closed) something Staging Ground should fix?

Comment: @ravenspoint These users can always go to Yahoo!Answers or something similar where there's no question closure. The problem: because there's no question closure, the question quality is so poor that the experts all left the site already. Moderation is critical to the success of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 12):

Okay I think I have the flowchart of how all of this mess transpired.

- User A asked question.
- User A's question was closed.
- User B wanted to answer User A's question.
- User B created and populated a self-answered question, addressing User A's question.

User A's question is still off-topic, but I want to be careful here.  **Asking about algorithms is not off-topic.**

The way that the question reads is that it describes the Traveling Salesman problem and then asks the community for a solution.  Given a matrix, they want to be able to determine what attractions they should visit to maximize their sum of attractiveness.

Okay - that means this isn't *exactly* about an algorithm.  They're looking for some kind of implementation to this question.

User B wants to answer this question *anyway*, so they spin up a separate question and answer.  Their question is *also* off-topic, since the way it's framed, it reads as a "hey, give me this solution"-style question, so it gets downvoted and closed.

What was the real issue here?  Well, I can't exactly fault someone for wanting to answer a question, but the point of closure is for a question to be made on-topic.  I do think that the original question *could* be made on-topic, although I'm not sure exactly how yet.

Comment: "I can't exactly fault someone for wanting to answer a question"  Surely the purpose of this site is to answer questions?  It has become very hard to do so.  It often seems the point of the site has become to humiliate the inexperienced and those with poor English writing skills.

Comment: No @ravenspoint, the purpose is to [build a repository of answers to questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315129/1079354).  This repository must be of the *highest* caliber, and we cannot afford to have anything that we deem to be low quality persist. This ruthless pursuit of perfection is done for and in the service of all.

Comment: @Makoto - After looking at the original question, I don't see what's wrong with it.  Yet you stated *"User A's question is still off-topic"* - would you elaborate on that?

Comment: @ravenspoint - while I can appreciate the answer you provided, I think it would have been better received if you had rewritten the question in a more concise way. Given your years of experience here, I think you could have done better than *"Develop an algorithm to solve X..."* - this reads more like a list of demands from a help vampire than an actual question. I actually think the original has a lot more to offer...

Comment: @EatenbyaGrue  I am not comfortable re-writing other people's questions.  Seems rude.  What if I misunderstood the question?  I have the impression that concise questions are even more rapidly closed.

Comment: @EatenbyaGrue:  The original question reads to me as if it is asking for an implementation to the solution of their question of the Traveling Salesman problem, it's just that they're providing the constants for us to use as part of the exercise.  It's not a question *about* the algorithm or a question in their approach to address a subset solution to the problem.

Comment: @ravenspoint - I think you misunderstood. I am referring to [your reposted version of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74464006/travelling-salesman-problem-with-limited-time-and-node-scores) - not the OP's question.

Comment: @ravenspoint Re: *What if I misunderstood the question?* - Then how can you be sure that you know the solution to it? If you don't know what the question is about, *close* it. Don't try to answer it and guess.

Comment: I can never sure my answer is correct.  Who could?  That is why I want to answer questions in public, so people can improve my answers.  Isn't that the whole point?

Comment: @ravenspoint:  If you're not reasonably confident that your answer is correct - when you provide one, that is - then you're not really helping contribute to the main goal of the site.  Guessing can be OK but it's better if we have a lot of high quality answers to questions.

Comment: There is a yawning gap between confidence and a guess.  Of course, I am not a ruthless pursuer of perfection.

Comment: I don't follow the reasoning in your answer "*Their question is also off-topic, since the way it's framed, it reads as a "hey, give me this solution"*". So long as the problem requirements are clear and narrowly scoped, isn't asking for a solution the purpose of a question on the site? I'm not sure how the linked question is supposed to be improved further, other than cosmetic edits.

Comment: I second @cigien's confusion regarding the remarks about *"hey, give me this solution"*, though I think the linked question is pretty unclear, relying almost entirely on the link to the previous question for the actual details.

Comment: @RyanM Oops, I meant the original question, not the duplicate one that's the the primary subject of the Meta post.

Comment: @ravenspoint " Real life, where things actually need to get done, is messy and imperfect." . True enough. That's why other sites such as Reddit, Quora, Codidact exist or services such as IRC and Discord. If we're going to make very incomplete definitions to force a point: the definition of laziness is to sign up to Stack Overflow and then not sign up to any other site or service anymore, just settle down here and dump all your stuff on the same pile so you don't have to make an effort to use the right venue for the right question.

Comment: @cigien:  The [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74464006/travelling-salesman-problem-with-limited-time-and-node-scores) leads off with the same premise as all other "give me teh codez"-style questions.  Looking at it, there's really not a whole lot that could be reformed to make the question on-topic.  So, this is the limiting factor - even if it's a self-answered question then the question still needs to be on-topic.

Comment: @RyanM:  The above is my clarification about the remarks.  Let me know if there's still some clarification needed.

Comment: @Makoto Could you clarify what you mean by "give me teh codez" exactly? I've often heard that phrase used for questions that ask for a solution without showing an attempt *but* are also unclear or asking for too much. In this particular case, the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74456982) is asking for a solution to a problem that's clearly defined, and sufficiently narrowly scoped. It looks on-topic to me. Is the only issue you have with the question the fact that it doesn't show an attempt, or is there some other objection I'm missing? I agree the duplicate is unclear.

Comment: @cigien:  My remark to "also being off-topic" is related to the second question.  That's a question that only provides a requirements list.  There's really no way to redeem a question that's just a "hey, here are my requirements, do this"-kind of question.  There's just not one correct answer to those kinds of questions, which is problematic.  There is a lot of prior art on this.

Comment: @cigien: For the first question, what I'm observing is that the question is not asking *about* the algorithm, it's asking for us to implement a specific solution using that algorithm.  I don't know how on-topic that is entirely, and I admit that I could be wrong on that.

Comment: @Makoto The first question was originally definitely tagged inappropriately (it had 2 languages mentioned, and [genetic-algorithm] for some reason). I suspect the OP was trying to get additional attention on the question. If the question had asked for a solution in a specific language that would have been fine. Now that it's been edited to be an algorithm question (rather than focusing on a single language) it's still fine, and IMO more useful this way, as readers can now adapt the algorithm to whatever language they want.

Comment: @cigien:  Oh good, maybe I'll take a closer look at this.  If it could be made on-topic, then that's perfectly fine with me!

Comment: "This repository must be of the highest caliber, and we cannot afford to have anything that we deem to be low quality persist." If only it were so. There are, however, *vastly* more unclosed questions on the site than could be consistent with everyone being on board with that mindset.

Answer (score 6):

If the "new similar question" is sufficiently improved that it is not low quality, off-topic or unanswerable, then I see no problem; we *want* people to ask questions that are high quality, on-topic and answerable.

If the new similar question is bad like the original one, then downvote and vote to close. If the new question is good, then I don't see any problem; the person asking a good question which is not a duplicate of another good question is improving Stack Overflow, not doing anything wrong.

---

It is different if the author of the original question is the one asking the new one; in that case, they are bypassing the system which is supposed to ensure that their question is sufficiently improved before it is re-opened and starts accepting answers again. If the original author were able to ask their question in a different way that makes it high quality, on-topic and answerable, then they should edit rather than post a new question. The latter *is* against the rules, and (in practice) the new question from the same author usually isn't sufficiently improved to avoid being closed again.

Answer (score -27):

> ... instead of waiting for the other one to be reopened ...

I have tried doing this many times.  Closed questions almost never get re-opened.

The OP, usually a nooby, gets discouraged by the closing.  They probably never come back to the site.

Premature closing of questions is very harmful and is now so prevalent that this site is almost unusable for serious work.

Comment: There is no premature closing. Every question is closed well past the time it needed to be clarified.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "serious work", but...if a question needs to be closed, a question needs to be closed.  What edits could you suggest that would make the question on-topic, or do I have a completely wonky understanding of the question itself such that it *is* on-topic?

Comment: So ... you may have been trying to answer a poor question.  It has happened to me a few times too.  What we both then need to do is, understand better what makes a good or a poor question, and work on the good ones.

Comment: *Closed questions almost never get re-opened* — because almost always nobody bothers to fix them. If you want a question reopened, fix it. Optionally, leave some remarks somewhere to tell the reopen reviewers why it should be reopened.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: *"Premature closing of question is very harmful"* I suggest reading [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing), however, the TL;DR is "Zero seconds." How can something be premature if the time to do something is zero seconds? We'd have to start voting to close questions before we read them, or even before they are posted. *Maybe* the staging ground will be a little of that, as the question will never actually be posted?

Comment: "Premature closing of questions is very harmful" Not even close. If anything, every question should **start out** closed and have to be approved before getting answers.