# Add suggestions for non-native English speakers to "How to Ask"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, help-center

Given how often we see "English is not my native language" in the questions, would it make sense to suggest in FAQ that non-native speakers specify their language as part of the question? My hope is that declaring asker's native language would attract those who can help him/her understand the answers, much like it happened [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306093/user-does-not-speak-english-and-duplicates-questions).

Another possibility is mentioning non-English Stack Overflow sites in FAQ.

Comment: Mentioning non-English sites where relevant is fine, but encouraging a sort of sub-SO within this site with attempts at translation seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: It is really of no concern.  We write answers for everybody, not just the OP.  If they can't understand an answer because they don't master English well enough, well, too bad but it doesn't matter.  Feel free to edit it out.

Comment: *attract those who can help him/her understand the answers* - Note that the answer there includes, *we finally had a **2h** SO-chat session*. If folks in the community are willing and able to devote that kind of time helping one person then more power to them, but I think it's dangerous to imply that this level of help is available.

Answer (score 4):

Non. Je n'aime pas.

J'ai mis beaucoup d'effort en demandant ma question. De plus, en me disant que si je met ma langue maternelle dans ma question, vous allez me donner un expectation, que quelqu'un vais aller traduire ma question, et m'aider. En meme fois, la communaute aura un impact negative sur ma question. Je vous detestera tous.

---

For all you non-speaking French people out there...

You will give me an expectation that someone *will* come help me in my native language, or will translate my question for me.

This expectation will already impact the main experience that many of these users have. I've found a lot of "non-English" questions with poor grammar, spelling and punctuation (to the expectations of a native speaker), that get plenty of down votes. Furthermore, not everyone even understands these languages. While you *could* pull up Google Translate, the accuracy of those translations are poor, let alone will anyone even bother to do that.

Nothing gets improved. The asker is happy, the community gets mad with more questions like this, and all heck breaks loose.

<sup>Another thing to add, though not directly related to the main content of this answer, is that I have been criticized in the past for trying to help other users in their native language. If I can tell, from code, or from the language in the question that the asker speaks a language that I speak, such as French, I will generally try to 'bilingualise' my comments, so that both the asker and others' in the community may benefit. That's been met with a lot of criticism from various users in the community.</sup>

Comment: The idiom is *[all hell breaks loose](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_hell_breaks_loose#Verb)*.